# chai.assert() wont run methods in a test before the assertion (chai assert lib with protractor)

Tags: protractor, assert, chai, e2e-testing

First time I post an issue on SO, I hope I'm doing it right.

```
it (' :: 2.0 service creation :: should fill out service info tab', function(){
    createNewService.setServiceName(e2eConfig.newServiceDetails.basicServiceName);
    createNewService.selectCategory();
    createNewService.setIntroText(e2eConfig.newServiceDetails.introText);
    createNewService.selectParent();
    createNewService.uploadIcon();
    createNewService.nextTab();
    //right now assert will fire off without running the methods above because
    //we are still on the infoTab
    assert(($(createNewService.selectors.infoTab).isDisplayed()) == true, 'did not move to the next tab');
},20000);
```

What this test does is it fills the inputs, selects drop-downs where necessary and uploads a file.

The test then attempts to switch to the next tab in the widget.

To determine whether it managed to switch to the next tab I want to make a chai library assertion with a custom message.

- with the current code the assert will return true because it sees the infoTab and the test will fail without running any of the methods before the assert
- if I change the assert line to look for '!== true', then it's going to run the methods and move on

In any case, would it be better to do this in a different manner or perhaps use expect instead of assert?

[Chai assert API](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/)

[Chai expect API](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Protractor function calls return promises that resolve asynchronously, so if the functions you defined on `createNewService` are all calling Protractor functions you'll have to wait for them resolve before calling the assert. Try something like the following:

```
it (' :: 2.0 service creation :: should fill out service info tab', function(done) {
  createNewService.setServiceName(e2eConfig.newServiceDetails.basicServiceName);
  createNewService.selectCategory();
  createNewService.setIntroText(e2eConfig.newServiceDetails.introText);
  createNewService.selectParent();
  createNewService.uploadIcon();
  createNewService.nextTab().then(function() {
    assert.eventually.strictEqual($(createNewService.selectors.infoTab).isDisplayed(), true, 'did not move to the next tab');
    done();
  });
},20000);
```

A few things to note:

- This example assumes that `createNewService.nextTab()` returns a promise.
- You'll need to use a library like [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/) to handle assertions on the values returned from promises. In your code you're asserting that a promise object == true, which is truthy due to coercion.
- Since your functions run asynchronously, you'll need to pass a callback to your anonymous function then call it when your test is finished. Information about testing asynchronous code can be found [here](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).